# Best practice of cache management

Tags: c#, caching

I want to use AOP to apply cache functionality to all of method of BLL layer in my website.
Just like below:

```
[Cacheable(new string[] { "id" }, GroupName = "UserInfoByID", LiveTime = "00:05:00")]
public UserInfo GetUserInfoByID(int id)
{
    return UserDAO.GetUserInfo(id);
}
```

The first argument of `Cacheable` attribute figures out which arg of method will be used to create cache key. The second argument `GroupName` figures out the prefix of cache key. As the above example, a key-"UserInfoByID(123)" will be generated (supposing the query id be 123). I create another attribute:

```
[PurgeCache(new string[] { "userInfo.ID" }, GroupName = "UserInfoByID")]
public void UpdateUserInfo(UserInfo userInfo)
{
    UserDAO.UpdateUserInfo(userInfo);
}
```

It will use userInfo.ID and the same GroupName-`UserInfoByID` to generate a same key to purge cache: `UserInfoByID(123)`. Is it every simple to use and elegant? There is, however ,a very tough problem. I have another method:

```
public void ManageUser(int[] userID, int status)
{
    UserDAO.ManageUser(userID, status);
}
```

The method is used to change user's status. How can I refresh cache after execution? Should I generate key with `int[] userID` one by one and purge all of them? Is it too complex in consideration of high performance cache, even though it's just a very simple case. Supposing I have a list query mehod:

```
[Cacheable(new string[] { "regionID" }, GroupName = "UserList", LiveTime = "00:05:00")]
public List<UserInfo> GetUserList(int regionID)
{
    List<UserInfo> result = UserDAO.GetUserList(regionID);
    return result;
}
```

If I change user's status to disactiviated, how can I refresh the cache of above method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I built a small aop caching fw sometime ago, [MbCache](http://code.google.com/p/mbcache/), where I decided to let invalidation be an "explicit" operation rather than a configuration issue. Made things a lot easier.

Even though this fw uses code configuration rather than attributes (I don't really like the attribute thingy for different reasons - personal opinion), the same could be applicable here I guess. You should maybe remove your PurgeCacheAttribute and instead let that be some runtime operation/method?

This is how [invalidation](http://code.google.com/p/mbcache/wiki/Invalidate) is made in MbCache, maybe that will give you some ideas?